# iOS App Rejected due to use of background location mode for geofence

Tags: ios, location, geofencing

Recently apple has rejected my app due to below reason.

Below is the explanation of functionality:

1. We require to track user entry and exit in the regions received from the server
2. If users enter in some defined region, We are also calling web-service and prepare the new set of geofence. We defined this type of fences as reset fence.
3. So it is also possible, Some time app is in background mode and user will might be enter in reset fence region so we require to call web-service and set up new fences in background.

We have used below flags of info.plist so app can run in background:

1 Required background modes:

- App downloads content from the network
- App registers for location    updates

2 Required device capabilities:

- armv7

Additional information:
App supports iOS 5.0 to iOS 8

---

Reason:

2.16: Multitasking Apps may only use background services for their intended purposes: VoIP, audio playback, location, task completion, local notifications, etc.
----- 2.16 -----

We found that your app uses a background mode but does not include functionality that requires that mode to run persistently. This behavior is not in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines.

We noticed your app declares support for location in the UIBackgroundModes key in your Info.plist but does not include features that require persistent location.

It would be appropriate to add features that require persistent use of real-time location updates while the app is in the background or remove the "location" setting from the UIBackgroundModes key. If your application does not require persistent, real-time location updates, we recommend using the significant-change location service or the region monitoring location service.

For more information on these options, please see the "Starting the Significant-Change Location Service" and "Monitoring Shape-Based Regions" sections in the Location Awareness Programming Guide.

If you choose to add features that use the Location Background Mode, please include the following battery use disclaimer in your Application Description:

"Continued use of GPS running in the background can dramatically decrease battery life."

---

Any one please suggest me that

1. In my case what info.plist settings i should use ?
2. What other changes i should check in the code. ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you need to get the user's exact location once he enters a region? If not, you can simply send the server that region's center coordinate and ask it to calculate the new regions.

Comment: Hello Gad, Can you please suggest me the info.plist changes and how to reset fence in background mode.

Comment: Hello Nikh, I have the same issue , how do you solve it , I use location services in background ,

Comment: Can you please look into my this thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26118210/geofence-ios8-require-background-mode-for-ios-geofencing/26944037#26944037 . If you still confused then please let me ask so i will make you understand more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to remove Location updates from the `UIBackgroundModes`.

Now, you need to write some code to handle what happens when the user enters a region. I wrote a very simplistic outline of a solution which detects when the user enters a region, sends that region's center to the web service (so it knows how to calculate the new regions) and monitors the new regions that are returned.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{
    [self setNewFencesFromWebServiceAtCoordinates:[(CLCircularRegion *)region center] withCompletionBlock:^(NSArray *locations) {
        int i = 0;
        for (CLLocation * location in locations)
        {
            i++;
            CLLocationCoordinate2D regionCenter = [location coordinate];
            [manager startMonitoringForRegion:[[CLCircularRegion alloc] initWithCenter:regionCenter radius:100.0 identifier:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"location %d",i]]];
        }
    }];
}

- (void)setNewFencesFromWebServiceAtCoordinates:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinates withCompletionBlock:(void(^)(NSArray * locations))completion
{
    NSArray * newRegions;

    // Write code to get the new regions from the web service and store them in an array of locations

    completion(newRegions);
}
```